# I am having problem with unknown space between navigation DIV and UL list

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle link as you can see when we mouse over the home navigation it change the color of its background but there is little space left between the header and home navigation why is the space coming how to solve it? Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkda9bd8c/).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #e6b756;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, orange 75%, black 100%);
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 230%;
}

header h3 {
  font-size: 125%;
}

footer {
  font-size: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e6b756;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  background-color: #e6b756;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #EAEAEA
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into using a normalize-ing css file to ensure elements are initialized the same across browsers.

It will typically contain `ul { margin:0 }` which is needed to get rid of the gap you describe

Answer (score 1):

Some HTML tags have specific properties given to them. For a full list, you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).

In this case, HTML automatically initializes `ul` tags to have `margin-top: 1em`. You need to add `margin: 0`, or specifically `margin-top: 0` to your `ul` tag to remove the top margin.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #e6b756;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, orange 75%, black 100%);
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 230%;
}

header h3 {
  font-size: 125%;
}

footer {
  font-size: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #e6b756;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  background-color: #e6b756;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #EAEAEA
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <img src="images/pumpkin.gif" alt="Pumpkin" width="85">
    <h2>The Halloween Store</h2>
    <h3>For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
  </header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="props.html">Props</a></li>
      <li><a href="costumes.html">Costumes</a></li>
      <li><a href="masks.html">Masks</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <h1>Welcome to my site.<br>Please come in and stay awhile.</h1>
    <p>I started this web site because Halloween has always been my favorite holiday. But during the last year, I started selling some of my favorite Halloween products, and they've become quite a hit.</p>
    <p>If you click on the Personal link, you can browse my favorite Halloween pictures, stories, and films. And if you join my email list, I will keep you up-to-date on all things Halloween.</p>
    <h2>Product of the week</h2>
    <p><img src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="Deranged cat" width="150"></p>
    <p><a href="????">20" Deranged cat</a></p>
    <h3>My guarantee</h3>
    <p>If you aren't completely satisfied with everything you buy from my site, you can return it for a full refund. <strong>No questions asked!</strong></p>
  </main>
```